# Sharing files/ photos/ music between Windows 8 users on same computer

Tags: windows-8, file-sharing, multiple-users

Just purchased Windows 8 on a new computer. spent all day transferring photos, music and documents from old computer and laptop.

When my partner logged into Windows 8 (different user) she could not access any of these files, despite them being 'shared between homegroup'

Only option seems to be to re-upload all these files in duplicate (about 300gb...)
Any ideas why these files aren't sharing, it's like having a separate hard-drive per user!

Comment: Did you get an error message when trying to access them, or were the images just not there?

Comment: Just not there. I uploaded the files to my account (where they are readily accessible), but assumed they would be for all users on the same computer

Answer (score 2):

Just use C:\Users\Public and store things in the Public Documents/Pictures/etc. folders there.  That's what it is there for.

You can view/browse them easily via Explorer on the left Navigation pane under "Libraries" since those folders are included in the default libraries.  If you don't see it in the nav pane, click View, Navigation Pane, and check `Show Libraries`.

> The Public Folder is a Windows folder that you can use to share files
>   with other people that either use the same computer, or connect to it
>   over a network. The Public folder is located in the Users folder of
>   your root directory (for example, C:\Users\Public).
>
> Everyone with a user account and password on your computer can access
>   the Public folder. However, you may decide whether anyone on the
>   network can access the Public folder. (By default, network access is
>   turned off). Public Folder Contents
>
> The Public Folder contains no files until someone adds those. It does
>   have default folders, named for content type, to make it easier for
>   organizing files:
>
> ```
> Public Documents
>
> Public Downloads
>
> Public Music
>
> Public Pictures
>
> Public Videos
> ```

[Source](http://windows.about.com/od/organizingyourstuff/f/what_is_public_folder.htm)

Comment: It may be nice to show where you got the information from - You've shown it's a quote (cool), but please do cite the reference.

Comment: Dave, it's in there, just without a direct link (check the edit page)  The quote is there to expound on the info I provided above the quote.

Comment: I can't see it, nor the edit page?! How odd

Comment: @DaveRook http://superuser.com/posts/745975/edit - look there, at the bottom.  I didn't really like linking directly to about.com on the actual answer :)  Hence the [1] after Public Videos.

Comment: Updated, that is better! +1

Answer (score 1):

Homegroups are for sharing between computers. In your case, you just need to ensure her account has permissions to the folders you created/own.

If you need help figuring out how to do that, I'd suggest checking with MS (like [File and Folder Permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx)  and [What are permissions?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/what-are-permissions#1TC=windows-7)), and/or one of many Internet links such as this: [How to Allow or Deny Access Permissions to Users and Groups in Windows 8 and 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2815-permissions-allow-deny-access-users-groups-windows-8-a.html).

Suggestion: You may want to make specific folders on the drive to put these shared things in instead of dumping them in your personal "photos", "music", etc. folders.

Answer (score 0):

The **Homegroup** option is related to a computer network, not to multiple users on the same machine.

Create a folder on non-system drive (e.g. D, or E) and copy the files you want to share there (1 file for start and test). By default, all users on the machine should have access right to that folder.

If the other user still cannot play the files:

1. Right-click the folder
2. Select **Properties**
3. Open the **Security** tab
4. Select the users and click **Edit...**
5. Then, select the permissions you want the other user to have (Read should be enough)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on windows 8 and not windows 8.1, you should still have access to Libraries in explorer. You can place files in the 'Public Documents' folder in the Documents library or (Public Pictures in the Pictures library etc.) to allow other users with a username or password on your machine to access those files.